# Cannot login to server after file permissions change

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login, root

I am using Ubuntu server. I ran:

```
chmod -R 700 /
```

when I was logged in as root. Now when I try to login as my normal user I immediately get kicked out. Is there anyway to log back in to the server whether it is root or whoever so that I can change the permissions? or am I totally screwed? I dont think I have root access enabled in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. I do have physical access to the server. I really need some help here.

Comment: Does server downtime matter? You could remove the hard drive, plug it into another machine, get the files off you need and then wipe the drive and start over with the server from scratch?

Comment: Downtime does NOT matter.  That's a great idea! I didn't even think of that. I'll try that.  Thanks.  Just out of curiosity, would you how to do it another way?

Comment: I can't think of any other way besides the one in the link that @mpy mentions.

Comment: Once I have the hard drive out of the server, should I put it into another machine that has ubuntu desktop and pull the files off the HD that way or how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Yeah, that should work. You'll likely still have to update the permissions of the files you copy.

Comment: so I put the ubuntu SERVER hard drive into a computer with ubuntu DESKTOP.  The hard drive is directly put into the motherboard.  THe new drive now shows up under "computer" on the ubuntu desktop gui for a second then disappears. So it recognizes the drive but is not obtainable.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I recommend you post that as a new superuser question, and provide a link to it here in the comments.