# ec2-user cannot login after permission changed in AWS

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, putty

I have AWS ec2-user with Amazone AMI.

Accidentaly, I changed the ownership of the all the accounts to root in the root directory.

```
chown -R root:root ./
```

Now, I cannot login to my ec2-user account using Putty.

I found a similar situation in this link
[Cannot login to server after file permissions change](https://superuser.com/questions/612521/cannot-login-to-server-after-file-permissions-change)
but my server is on AWS and not physical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS Management console (https://aws.amazon.com/console/) to add another user with appropriate (we'll presume the user will need root/sudo) privileges.  Undo the damage; you can then delete the "new user" you added.

Comment: Thanks man but didn't work.